# Castle Windsor LifestylePerWebRequest - Only seems to resolve on the first web request for ISession

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor

I'm setting up my MVC project so that I resolve my `ISession`'s on a PerWebRequest basis.

Here's what I have so far:

In my Castle Windsor Setup I register my `ISession` using a factory method:

`Component.For<ISession>().UsingFactoryMethod(ctx => MsSql2008SessionFactory.OpenSession()).LifestylePerWebRequest()`

In my `Global.asax` `Application_Start()` I Bind my `ISession` to NHibernate's `CurrentSessionContext` each time a request begins:

```
BeginRequest += delegate{
            CurrentSessionContext.Bind(
                     MsSql2008SessionFactory.OpenSession());
                       };

EndRequest += delegate{
             var session = MsSql2008SessionFactory
                             .SessionFactory
                               .GetCurrentSession();
              if (session != null)
              {
                session.Dispose();
              }
             CurrentSessionContext
                     .Unbind(MsSql2008SessionFactory
                         .SessionFactory);
        };
```

The first time I make a request to a page everything works fine.
The second time I make a request to a page I get an exception stating:

> Session is closed! Object name: 'ISession'.

What am I not doing correctly?

Comment: You should be using a WindsorInstaller to wire all this up

Comment: BeginRequest and EndRequest are not guaranteed to execute on the same thread either

Comment: As well everything you do with Nhibernate should be wrapped in a transaction

Comment: one other thing to note when dealing with CurrentSessionContext. Things get tricky of you don't check to see if it is already bound before unbinding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this turned out to be quite simple.

The repository that I was injecting my `ISession` into had a `Singleton` lifestyle.

This meant that the `ISession` that had been injected on the first request was also being used for the subsiquent requests (because my repository class was only being created at the start of the application) and was thus already disposed.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do things may work for you. I use Fluent Nhibernate just in case some of the config doesn't jive.

```
public interface INHibernateSessionFactoryHelper
{
    ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory();
}


public class NhibernateSessionFactoryHelper
{
    private static readonly string ConnectionString =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnectionString"].ToString();

    public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .ProxyFactoryFactory("NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate")
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<EntityMap>())
            .Database(
                MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(ConnectionString).AdoNetBatchSize(1000))
            .Cache(
                c =>
                c.ProviderClass<SysCacheProvider>().UseSecondLevelCache().UseQueryCache().UseMinimalPuts())
            .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty(Environment.GenerateStatistics, "true")
                                          .SetProperty(Environment.SessionFactoryName, "My Session Factory")
                                          .SetProperty(Environment.CurrentSessionContextClass, "web"))
            .Diagnostics(d => d.Enable().OutputToFile(@"c:\temp\diags.txt"))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

Then my Windsor installer looks like this

```
public class NHibernateInstaller:IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component.For<ISessionFactory>().Instance(NhibernateSessionFactoryHelper.CreateSessionFactory()));
        container.Register(Component.For<ISessionManager>().ImplementedBy<SessionManager>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
    }
}
```

I have omitted the code for the SessionManager I use. Let me know if you would like it

UPDTAE: Here is the code I use for managing sessions and transactions( I found pieces of this scattered about the Internet but it all worked well without too much modification. ISessionManager is wired up per my previous example and injected in to the constuctor of my Services.

```
public interface ISessionManager : IDisposable
{
    ISession Session { get; set; }
    ISession GetSession();
}

public class SessionManager : ISessionManager
{
    private readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private TransactionScope _scope;
    public SessionManager(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    #region ISessionManager Members

    public ISession Session { get; set; }

    public ISession GetSession()
    {
        if (Session == null)
        {
            Session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
            if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(_sessionFactory))
            {
                _scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions {IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted});
                Session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
                CurrentSessionContext.Bind(Session);
            }
        }

        Session = _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        Session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Never;
        return Session;
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(_sessionFactory))
        {
            CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(_sessionFactory);
        }
        try
        {
            Session.Transaction.Commit();
            _scope.Complete();
            _scope.Dispose();
            Session.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (Session.Transaction != null && Session.Transaction.IsActive)
            {
                Session.Transaction.Rollback();
            }
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Session.Close();
            Session.Dispose();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Example Constructor:

```
private readonly ISessionManager _sessionManager;
private readonly ISession _session;
 public UserService(ISessionManager sessionManager)
    {

        _sessionManager = sessionManager;
        _session = sessionManager.GetSession();

     }
```

Comment: Session factory should be singleton as well.

Comment: Thanks @CodeJammr. This is pretty much what I have already. How are you ensuring that your Sessions remain open when utilising IEnumerable or IQueryable items inside your views? That's the main issue I'm trying to solve.

Comment: I Use ViewModels. My views never see an IEnumerable or IQueryable returned from my data layer. This is what ViewModels were designed for. I use a "Service" approach so to say. Example: IProdutService is wired up with Windsor and injected into the constructor of the Products controller. As far as the session staying open. I have not run into any issues. I suspect there is something else causing this problem for you.

Comment: You may want to go downloa a trial of Nhibernate Profiler to get a better Idea of what is going on.

Comment: I basically inject ISession into my repository. For the first request everything works fine. On the second request, the ISession.IsOpen is false. I'm using the ISession like `return _session.CreateCriteria<MyType>().Future<MyType>().AsQueryable();`

Comment: Please see the updated answer. Something is going on with the Session and Per Web Request most likely.

Comment: Thanks @CodeJammr. I'm doing something very similar to this. The only difference is that instead of injecting my sessionManager I inject an ISession. If I inject the sessionManager than it works fine but I expect the injection if ISession to just work. Something must be closing it but I'm not sure what. Perhaps I'll just do it this way until I figure out what's going on. Thanks for your help mate. Much appreciated.

Comment: You still have to properly manage ISession. Most people wrap it rather than just inject a ISession

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11004/discussion-between-jamie-dixon-and-code-jammr)